# How to fix Java file versions and compile versions are different in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

When I use VSCode to run a Java program, it always show a Error that compiled class file is can't be recognized because of the class file versions.

I have checked Mac's environment. `javac -version` and `java -version` shows `javac 1.8.0_181` and `java 1.8.0_181`.

```
class Hello{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

If I run the code, It will show the Error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Hello has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.65535), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: Do you compile with a higher version of the JDK and turn it on with a lower version on your computer ？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall jdk8 clean ([Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903))
2. Install jdk11 ([Link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html))
3. Add "vmArgs": "--enable-preview" in launch.json
4. F1, "Java: Clean the Java language server workspace" and "Java: Force Java Compilation"
5. Run standalone file again

Comment: Can I change visual-studio-code to solve this problem rather than change JDK8 to JDK11?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried and haven't seen anything like that working. Its a problem with the microsoft java that runs in VS Code.